# C++ Winapi, Popup window will open once but won't re-open

Tags: c++, winapi, button, popup

I am using Windows, Visual Studio 2015. The problem I am having is I have a button that will open a child pop-up window, it does it fine the first time but once you close the popup window and click the button again it doesn't re-open.

I have hwnd2 a global variable because currently I don't know how to access the variable in another function unless it's global. Just letting you know before you guys are like "eww, global variables"

There may be something completely wrong but searching the internet constantly got me this far and no one was really specific/in depth.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32Project1.h"
#include <Windows.h>

#define IDB_CLICK_ME 200
HWND hwnd2;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc2(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine , int iCmdShow)
{
    wchar_t wzAppName[] = L"GameLauncher";
    wchar_t wzAppName2[] = L"GameTest";
    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd;
    WNDCLASS wndclass, wndclass2;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = wzAppName;
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    wndclass2.lpfnWndProc = WndProc2;
    wndclass2.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass2.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass2.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass2.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass2.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass2.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass2.lpszClassName = wzAppName2;
    wndclass2.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass2.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;


    RegisterClass(&wndclass);
    RegisterClass(&wndclass2);

    hwnd = CreateWindow(wzAppName, L"Tutorial", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    hwnd2 = CreateWindow(wzAppName2, L"Options", WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION, 100, 100, 500, 300, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateWindow(L"button", L"CLICK ME", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 5, 5, 200, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) IDB_CLICK_ME, NULL, NULL);
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            DrawText(hdc, L"Hello", -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wparam));
            {
                case IDB_CLICK_ME:
                    ShowWindow(hwnd2, 1);
                    UpdateWindow(hwnd2);
                    break;

            }

        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc2(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close the popup it's not just hidden. It's destroyed. You can handle `WM_CLOSE` if you want a different behavior (`DefWindowProc` just calls `DestroyWindow`).

Comment: To expand on this answer: this is because the default behavior of `WM_CLOSE`, which is sent when you click the window's close button, is to destroy the window.

Comment: @andlabs That would make sense, is there a way I can make it so it hides instead of being destroyed? (Changing the default behavior)

Comment: `CloseWindow()` minimizes a window (confusingly). You want `ShowWindow(hwnd2, SW_HIDE)`. Do this in `WM_CLOSE`, and **don't call DefWindowProc() there**.

Comment: @andlabs, Cheers and hth. - Alf 

I want to thank you both to take your time in helping me with this problem. I have gotten it fixed, I appreciate all the feedback immensely.